# How to add an XML file to eXist db form java script?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, exist-db

I'm new to eXist db.I can able to retrieve an xml file from db but how can i store my own XML file into a collection(collection name:test) using AJAX javaScript?

My Sample XML file looks like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
 <Configuration>
   <IP>120.6.45.35</IP>
   <Communitystring>public</Communitystring>
   <Template>generic</Template>
 </Configuration>
```

Please anyone help me?

Please answer my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use eXist RESTful API to add a document to the database. You'll have to issue an HTTP PUT request and send the document as message body. 
You need to specify content type as application/xml 
The address should be:

`(eXist_host):(port)/exist/rest/(path_to_target_collection)/(file_name)`

You can do it in JQuery AJAX or using a plain `XmlHttpRequest`.

See the [eXist developer guide](http://www.exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/devguide_rest.xml) for more information.